# Custom ActiveAdmin Filter for Date Range - Complex Logic in Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, ransack

I am trying to create a custom ActiveAdmin filter that takes date_range as a parameter. Every solution I've found has been for excessively simple model methods.

Is there a way to pass *both* parameters into the model ransacker method, and/or at the very least to control the order in which these parameters are passed as well as to know which one is being passed? (end_date vs. start_date -- start_date is passed first, whereas I might be able to work around this is end_date were sent first). Any alternative solution, which would not break all other filters in the application (ie, overwriting activeadmin filters to use scopes - this is one filter out of hundreds in the application) welcome as well.

Thank you!

admin/model.rb

```
filter :model_method_in, as: :date_range
```

models/model.rb

```
ransacker :model_method, :formatter => proc { |start_date, end_date|
    Model.complicated_method(start_date, end_date)
} do |parent|
   parent.table[:id]
end

...
def method_for_base_queries(end_date)
   Model.long_complicated_sql_call_using_end_date
end

def complicated_method(start_date, end_date)
    model_instances = method_for_base_queries(end_date)
    model_instances.logic_too_complex_for_sql_using_start_date
end
```

Similar question, but filter/model logic was simple enough for an alternative solution that didn't require both parameters to be passed in: [Custom ActiveAdmin filter for Date Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26116142/custom-activeadmin-filter-for-date-range])

Comment: I had the same question and could not solve it. I couldn't find any way to get both params at the same time.

Answer (score 6):

This might help. Given your index filter

```
filter :model_method, as: :date_range
```

you can write the following in your model:

```
  scope :model_method_gteq_datetime, -> (start_date) {
    self.where('users.your_date_column >= ?', start_date)
  }
  scope :model_method_lteq_datetime, -> (end_date) {
    # added one day since apparently the '=' is not being counted in the query,
    # otherwise it will return 0 results for a query on the same day (as "greater than")
    self.where('users.your_date_column <= ?', (Time.parse(end_date) + 1.day).to_date.to_s)
  }

  def self.ransackable_scopes(auth_object = nil)
    [model_method_gteq_datetime, :model_method_lteq_datetime]
  end
```

`..._gteq_datetime` and `..._lteq_datetime` is how Activeadmin interprets the two dates in a custom `date_range` index filter (see also the corresponding url generated after adding the filter).

I've written a sample query that fits my case (given that `users` is a model related to the current one), since I don't know the complexity of yours.

I'm using:

- Ruby 2.3.1
- Rails 5.0.7
- Activeadmin 1.3.0

Comment: This didnt work for me but if I change it from `model_method_gteq_datetime` to just `model_method_gteq` then it worked. ActiveModel 3.2 Ruby 3.1